# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x2000 and 500x128)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, runtime-error, word-embedding

I am implementing CBOW model on my own but I am facing the above mentioned error as stated in the title of the post. Please tell me what to do here is the model and my training:
#Setting up the CBOW module

```
class CBOW(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,vocab_size,embedding_dimensions):
        super().__init__()
        self.embeds= nn.Embedding(vocab_size,embedding_dimensions)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(embedding_dimensions,128)
        self.activation_unit = nn.ReLU()
        self.linear_2= nn.Linear(128,100)
        self.linear_3 = nn.Linear(100,vocab_size)
        self.activation_2 = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=-1)
    def forward(self,inputs):
        embeds = sum(self.embeds(inputs).view(1,-1))
        out = self.linear(embeds)
        out = self.activation_unit(out)
        out = self.linear_2(out)
        out = self.linear_3(out)
        out = self.activation_2(out)
        return out
    def get_word_embeds(self,word):
        word = torch.tensor(word_to_num[word])
        return self.embeddings(word).view(1,-1)

model = CBOW(vocab_size,embedding_dimensions)

for epochs in range(50):
    total_loss = 0
    
    for context, target in data:
        context_vector = make_context_vector(context,word_to_num)
        y_val  = model(context_vector)
        total_loss+= criterion(y_val,torch.tensor([word_to_num[target]]))
    
    
    #Updating gradients and parameters
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    total_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Here is the error which is shown:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-e153aa709855> in <module>
      4     for context, target in data:
      5         context_vector = make_context_vector(context,word_to_num)
----> 6         y_val  = model(context_vector)
      7         total_loss+= criterion(y_val,torch.tensor([word_to_num[target]]))
      8 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-21-a875854cd81d> in forward(self, inputs)
     11     def forward(self,inputs):
     12         embeds = sum(self.embeds(inputs).view(1,-1))
---> 13         out = self.linear(embeds)
     14         out = self.activation_unit(out)
     15         out = self.linear_2(out)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py in forward(self, input)
     92 
     93     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
---> 94         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
     95 
     96     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1751     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight):
   1752         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1753     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1754 
   1755 

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x2000 and 500x128)
```

Please tell me why is this error. Also as I am a newbie in deep-learning. I often encounter these type of errors. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong and what should I keep note of in order to avoid these type of errors in the future. Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Why are you flattening your features with `embeds = sum(self.embeds(inputs).view(1,-1))`. The first axis (the "batch axis") should remain untouched.

Comment: Its then giving an error of IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1). That's why I am flattening it

Comment: What is the shape of `inputs` and `self.embeds(inputs)`?

Comment: input that is given to the model is (49,500) and I don't know how can I print self.embeds(inputs) shape???

Comment: There is another model like this and it works smoothly however this is giving errors.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have finally got the answer the main issue was in the self.forward method in CBOW class.
in the first line of forward_method. It was written like this

```
embeds = sum(self.embeds(inputs).view(1,-1))
```

However the correct code would be

```
embeds = sum(self.embeds(inputs)).view(1,-1)
```

You don't enclose the reshape button within the parenthesis of sum() command. I hope it would help other fellow members.